# Passing string between Android Activities

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have a List Activity that when the user presses a line item, it passes the ID of the record to the next activity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(CustomerListActivity.this, CustomerEditActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("CUSTOMER_ID", id);

startActivity(intent);
```

I can see the data in the intent when debugging on that activity; however, when I get into the next activity, the data is not coming up with the below code.

```
Intent i = getIntent();
Bundle b = i.getExtras();
String s = b.getString("CUSTOMER_ID");
```

I have debugged and poked around in the variables window, but I do not see the Customer_ID=# value as I do on the previous activity.

Comment: `i.getStringExtra("CUSTOMER_ID","");`

Comment: post the entire `onCreate` code

Comment: make sure your passing String value only in Intent.

Answer (score 1):

You should call `String s = b.getStringExtra("CUSTOMER_ID");`

Answer (score 0):

You will have to call `getStringExtra()` method in New Activity to retrieve the value from Intent.

For example :

```
String custIdInNewAct= getIntent().getStringExtra("CUSTOMER_ID");
```

Answer (score 0):

Bundle contains data sent by the calling activity so

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
String s = b.getString("CUSTOMER_ID")`;
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Try this.It will work.Paste it on your next activity where you want to get data from intent.

```
 String s= getIntent().getExtras().get("CUSTOMER_ID")+"";
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it in a right way

```
//main activity
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), TargetActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("ParamKey", "key_value");
getActivity().startActivity(intent);

****
//TargetActivity
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.target_activity_layout);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    if (extras != null) {
        if (extras.get("ParamKey") != null)
            paramValue= extras.getString("ParamKey", "default_value");
    }
```